# Jquery - select one form (and its values) out of multiple forms with the same characteristics

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have few forms (button with few hidden fields)  on the page with similar characteristics (id makes them unique) , and I need to call an action using jQuery and AJAX (.click). My problem is to select form I want with jQuery. With the code I have at the moment there is no problem, as long as I select first form. I need help on setting up dynamic selector, how i can do that?? Thank you very much in advance!

My HTML:

```
Form 1: 
<form name="smsform-1" id="smsform-1" method='post' class="form-inline">
  <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='1'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms' value="Sample Text 1">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno' value='1111'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='1' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>

Form 2: 
<form name="smsform-2" id="smsform-2" method='post' class="form-inline">
  <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms' value="Sample Text 2">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno' value='2222'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='2' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>

Form 3: 
<form name="smsform-3" id="smsform-3" method='post' class="form-inline">
  <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='3'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms' value="Sample Text 3">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno' value='3333'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='3' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send_sms').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this), orderid = elem.attr('data-id'); 
        var testid = $("#id").val();
        var testsms = $("#sms").val();
    var testphoneno = $("#phoneno").val();
        console.log(orderid);
        console.log(testid);            
        console.log(testsms);
    console.log(testphoneno);
    alert(orderid + +testid + testsms + testphoneno);
    });
});
```

and working jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/cjqwkrh0/9/

Comment: try with class :  $('.btn').click(function(e) {

Comment: you can't give `id=send_sms` to all 3 submit button

Comment: First thing first you are using id='send_sms' on each form make it class='send_sms'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your button is always a **sibling** of the hidden fields you want...
I used this selector to find them.

**Notice** that I took the liberty to simplify your HTML.
I used classes, instead of names and ids, to determine wich is wich.
Then, a `each()` loop can retreive their respective values.

**Also notice** that I declared the `var` outside the `click()` function.
So they will be avalaible to your Ajax function *(not shown)* that will run after.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var orderid;
 var sms;
 var phoneno;
 
 $('.send_sms').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).siblings().each(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("orderid")){
    orderid = $(this).val();
    console.log(orderid);
   }
   if($(this).hasClass("sms")){
    sms = $(this).val();
    console.log(sms);
   }
   if($(this).hasClass("phoneno")){
    phoneno = $(this).val();
    console.log(phoneno);
   }
  });
  alert("OrderId: " +orderid+ " Message: " +sms+ " phone number: " +phoneno);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Form 1: <form name="smsform-1" method="post" class="form-inline">
 <input type="hidden" class="orderid" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" class="sms" value="Sample Text 1">
 <input type="hidden" class="phoneno" value="1111">
 <input type="submit" value='SMS' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs send_sms">
</form>

Form 2: <form name="smsform-2" method="post" class="form-inline">
 <input type="hidden" class="orderid" value="2">
 <input type="hidden" class="sms" id="sms_2" value="Sample Text 2">
 <input type="hidden" class="phoneno" value="2222">
 <input type="submit" value='SMS' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs send_sms">
</form>

Form 3: <form name="smsform-3" method="post" class="form-inline">
 <input type="hidden" class="orderid" value="3">
 <input type="hidden" class="sms" value="Sample Text 3">
 <input type="hidden" class="phoneno" value="3333">
 <input type="submit" value='SMS' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs send_sms">
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Take away: siblings - https://api.jquery.com/siblings/. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `.closest()` function in jQuery. It will look for the fist parent of the element that matches the expression you give it. It will find the form clicked.

inside the click event, can you add

`var clicked_button_form_id = elem.closest('form').attr('id');`

then you'll have a variable with the id of the form, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look attached snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this), orderid = elem.attr('data-id'); 
  var testid = $("#id_"+orderid).val();
  var testsms = $("#sms_"+orderid).val();
    var testphoneno = $("#phoneno_"+orderid).val();
  //console.log(orderid);
  //console.log(testid);   
  //console.log(testsms);
    //console.log(testphoneno);
    alert(orderid + +testid + testsms + testphoneno);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Form 1: <form name="smsform-1" id="smsform-1" method='post' class="form-inline">
 <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id_1' value='1'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms_1' value="Sample Text 1">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno_1' value='1111'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='1' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>

Form 2: <form name="smsform-2" id="smsform-2" method='post' class="form-inline">
 <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id_2' value='2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms_2' value="Sample Text 2">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno_2' value='2222'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='2' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>

Form 3: <form name="smsform-3" id="smsform-3" method='post' class="form-inline">
 <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id_3' value='3'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms_3' value="Sample Text 3">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno_3' value='3333'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='3' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //change of selector
 $("input[id='send_sms']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this), orderid = elem.attr('data-id'); 
  var testid = $("#id").val();
  var testsms = $("#sms").val();
    var testphoneno = $("#phoneno").val();
  console.log(orderid);
  console.log(testid);   
  console.log(testsms);
    console.log(testphoneno);
    alert(orderid + +testid + testsms + testphoneno);
 });
});
```

```html
Form 1: <form name="smsform-1" id="smsform-1" method='post' class="form-inline">
 <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='1'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms' value="Sample Text 1">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno' value='1111'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='1' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>

Form 2: <form name="smsform-2" id="smsform-2" method='post' class="form-inline">
 <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms' value="Sample Text 2">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno' value='2222'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='2' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>

Form 3: <form name="smsform-3" id="smsform-3" method='post' class="form-inline">
 <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='3'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sms' id='sms' value="Sample Text 3">
  <input type='hidden' name='phoneno' id='phoneno' value='3333'>
  <input type='submit' value='SMS' id='send_sms'  data-id='3' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
</form>
```

TRY NOW , i have changed the selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can bind `click` event on `submit` and get its `parent form` and find values of `input` with respect to `parent form`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var elem = $(this), orderid = elem.attr('data-id');
            var form = $(this).parent();


            var testid = form.find("input[name='id']").val();
            var testsms = form.find("input[name='sms']").val(); 
            var testphoneno = form.find("input[name='phoneno']").val();
            console.log(orderid);
            console.log(testid);
            console.log(testsms);
            console.log(testphoneno);
            alert(orderid + +testid + testsms + testphoneno);
        });
    });
```